# Download file at specific commit with Bitbucket REST API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

We are trying to find a way to download a single file from a Bitbucket project using the REST API at a specific *commit*.  Currently, we have the ability to download a file at a specific branch:

https://stash.domain.com:8443/rest/api/1.0/projects/our_project/src/main/java/com/SomeFile.java?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster

Note that the end of the URL, when decoded, contains the query parameter `at=refs/heads/master`, which refers to the `master` branch.  This also works for specific tags:

https://stash.domain.com:8443/rest/api/1.0/projects/our_project/src/main/java/com/SomeFile.java?at=refs%2Ftags%2Ftesttag1

Here the query parameter `at=refs/tags/testtag1` refers to the tag (commit) `testtag1`.

But because of the nature of our implementation, we would like to refer directly to a commit SHA-1 hash via the Bitbucket REST API.  Is this possible?

Obviously, one ugly workaround would be to just add a tag to every commit.  But this could bloat the repository and it also feels like an unnecessary hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528344/how-to-access-full-source-of-old-commit-in-bitbucket), I found one of the answers which tipped me off to the correct syntax.  Use this:

```
<URL>?at=commit_hash
```

For example:

https://stash.domain.com:8443/rest/api/1.0/projects/our_project/src/main/java/com/SomeFile.java?at=bed2dda5

Here is a table of three main endpoint types with the Bitbucket REST API:

```
query parameter   | role
---------------------------------------------
refs/heads/master | specify master branch
refs/tags/someTag | specify 'someTag' tag
at=bed2dda5       | specify commit #bed2dda5
```