# How to Clone an older commit in Bitbucket using Terminal

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to checkout a older commit in Bitbucket, Tried the solutions given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528344/how-to-access-full-source-of-old-commit-in-bitbucket) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813578/clone-specific-commit-bitbucket). Nothing worked for me, I think Bitbucket got updated a lot. I am able to clone only the newer commit.

Please guide me how to download the older version of the project in Bitbucket.

Comment: In what way did [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814361/354577) not help? Don't think of it as "cloning an older commit", but as cloning and then, in the local repository you've just created, checking out the commit or branch you want.

Comment: I am new to this bitbucket, I am not getting you, please tell me how to check out the commit i want in bitbucket?

Comment: You wouldn't do this "in bitbucket". Bitbucket is a cloud service, it doesn't exist on your local machine. After you've cloned the repository you're done with it. _In your local repository_  you could check out the old commit, either using Git or Mercurial (depending on what kind of repository it is). I've added some more reference questions above. Please see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7539130/354577) in particular, assuming you're working with a Git repository.

Comment: Thanks @Chris I thought Git and Bitbucket are different, I need to learn more about Git, the link in comment helped me.