# Browse Bitbucket 5.10.1 repository at old commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

This question has been asked before see for example [How to access full source of old commit in BitBucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528344/how-to-access-full-source-of-old-commit-in-bitbucket)

The Bitbucket GUI used to support this. In 5 steps you could do this in a completely non-intuitive way.

A alternative way to do it was to manipulate / construct URL's manually. Unfortunately URL schemes have changed in 5.10.1 it seems.

So there is no easy way to browse repositories at specific commit. But is there still a way do this for example in 5.10.1?

Comment: You've probably already considered it but just in case : can't you (temporarily) tag your commit then browse to 'Files' and point to it (you can either point to branches or tags here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is still possible via URL hacking. From my local 5.16.0 instance:

```
http://bitbucket.local/projects/PROJ/repos/myrepo/browse?at=b15afd066a1
```

Where `http://bitbucket.local` is my instance URL, `PROJ` is my project key, `myrepo` is my repo slug and `b15afd066a1` is my commit hash. Your commit hash doesn't need to be the *full* hash, Bitbucket will accept anything >= 4 characters. Obviously, the more of the hash you use the less chances of hitting a collision.