# Bitbucket - Download PART of source as zip

Tags: bitbucket

Related to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044749/bitbucket-download-source-as-zip), except is there a way to download only part of a repository?

I have a Unity book I'm working through and I have it in a git repo. My Unity repository is setup as such:

- Book
- Book Files (Sample Code)
- Version 4.6 Projects
- Version 5.0 Projects

As such, its ~300 megs to download. I can't just git clone due to firewall rules, but I can download the zip through the website.

Is it possible to download one of the folders? Say the 4.6 Projects folder? Without having to re-download the rest of the files?

Comment: Have you ever found a way?