# Jenkins: Transfer latest BitBucket commit over FTP

Tags: git, jenkins, ftp, bitbucket

I have BitBucket integrated with Jenkins and FTP.
But it takes everything.

Is it possible to grab latest BitBucket commit only then transfer it over FTP?

Answer (score 0):

You could [curl for the latest archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13044790/6309) of a BitBucket repo, and transfer that archive over FTP.

That way, it would not grab everything.

But that means not setting the SCM field of the Jenkins job, as that setting triggers a clone or fetch of the SCM url (here a BitBucket repo), and that does transfer everything.