# How can I create an Artifactory remote repository that uses a local Bitbucket server as the source for Composer packages

Tags: composer-php, bitbucket, artifactory

Our organization has a **locally** running instance of Artifactory, and also a local instance of Bitbucket.  We are trying to get them to play well together so that Artifactory can serve up our private PHP packages right out of Bitbucket.

Specifically, we'd like to create a Composer Remote Repository in Artifactory that serves up our private PHP packages, where those packages are sourced from git repositories on our local Bitbucket server.

Note that we'd rather not create and upload our own package zip files for each new package version, as suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/a3o410/deploy_php_composer_packages_from_git_github_or/).   Ideally, we just want to be able to commit changes to a PHP package in BitBucket, tag those changes as a new package version, and have that new version be automatically picked up and served by Artifactory.

The Artifactory [Composer documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/PHP+Composer+Repositories) suggests that this is possible:

> A Composer remote repository in Artifactory can proxy packagist.org
>   and other Artifactory Composer repositories for index files, and 
>   **version control systems such as GitHub or BitBucket**, or local
>   Composer repositories in other Artifactory instances for binaries.

We've spent a lot of time trying making this work, but haven't been able to do it.  The Remote Repository that we create always remains empty, no matter what we do.  **Can anyone offer an example to help, or even just confirm that what we're attempting isn't possible?**

For reference, we've been trying to find the right settings to put into this setup page:

[image: Adding a new Composer Remote Repository in Artifactory]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory won't download and pack the sources for you, it expects to find binary artifacts.

The mention of source control in the documentation refers to downloading the archives from source control systems, either uploaded there as archives (don't do that), or packed by the source control system on download request (that is what you are looking for).

You can use [this REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044749/bitbucket-download-source-as-zip) to download automatically generated zips from BitBucket. If you can configure the composer client to look for the packages in the right place, you're all set.