# Is there download option in Bitbucket server ? as it is available in Bitbucket cloud?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

This is in reference to this thread : [BitBucket - download source as ZIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044749/bitbucket-download-source-as-zip)

but i would like to know does bitbucket server also supports it ?

Ideally it should support , but i am not able to see this menu in our server installation.
Is there something that need to be installed or configured additionally ?

can you also point to equivalent bitbucker server api ? (for cloud it is https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/evzijst/git-tests/downloads)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This feature is built into Bitbucket Server/DC. It used to be a separate add-on, but it's been shipping natively for a while now.

Find a repo in your installation, go to the Source view in the left navigation. Select a branch and click on the `...` button and you'll see a Download option.

The equivalent API URL to get the download would be something like:

```
https://{BITBUCKET_URL}/rest/api/latest/projects/{PROJKEY}/repos/{reposlug}/archive?at={COMMIT_OR_BRANCHNAME}&format=zip
```

Full disclosure, I work at Atlassian.

Comment: It's more than a little hidden @daveruinseverything :)